# Adding sum in a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to recreate a simple project I have in my fundamentals class to javascript (from C++) but sum doesn't add every time the for loop runs. All other parts are ok but sum just lists the numbers in the order I put them in. Any help is appreciated

```
var num = prompt("Please enter an integer");
var lrg = num;
var sml = num;
var avg = num;
var sum = num;
var cnt = 10;

function runMath () {

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    var num = prompt("Please enter an integer");

    if (num > lrg) {
        lrg = num;
    } else {
        lrg = lrg;
    }

    if (num < sml) {
        sml = num;
    } else {
        sml = sml;
    }

    sum += num;

}
}

runMath();

avg = sum/cnt;
```

Comment: `prompt` returns a string.

Comment: Use `parseInt()` on the return value of `prompt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `prompt()` returns a String, whereas you are expecting a number. You can turn this into a number in a few different ways:

`parseInt("33")` will return `33`, instead of `"33"`

Likewise, shorthand would look like:

`+prompt("33")` will return `33`, instead of `"33"`

Comment: Thank you very much! Still learning and won't make that mistake again

Comment: You're welcome! If this worked for you, please mark my answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

All input is from the `prompt()` command is a string. You can convert it to an integer using `parseInt()`, but the user can enter something other than a number, so you will need to check if it [`isNaN()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) (is Not a Number), and deal with it differently if it is.

```
var num = prompt("Please enter an integer");
num = parseInt(num, 10)
if (isNaN(num)) {
  alert ("That's not a number")
  num = 0 // or do something else
}
```

Caution: `typeof NaN`  will return "number", so you can't rely on that as a test (see [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN))

An explanation of the `+` in `+prompt`: [Unary plus (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to add that in